# How to use bootstrap without CDN?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap on my website. First, I put CDN in the head, and everything is fine. Then I don't want to apply bootstrap by CDN, so I download the bootstrap file, and put the CSS part in the `<style>`, and put the js part in the `<script>`. But it didn't work, why?

This is the CDN code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Comment: add the code in your html(Check correct file path)

Answer (score 8):

Follow this step:

1. Go to **https://getbootstrap.com/** and then click a big "**Download**" button.
2. Scroll down to "**Compiled CSS and JS**" section, click "**Download**" button.
3. You'll have a file named like bootstrap-4.0.0-beta-dist.zip downloaded (according to current version).
4. **Extract it**. It'll have 2 folders inside: css & js.
5. Include them on your web project directory e.g. in `assets/bootstrap`.
6. Include them inside your html `<head>` script:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> <script src='assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
> ```

Good luck & keep learning!

Answer (score 2):

In your `<head>` section you can Link your CSS stylesheet

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
```

And Link Js files on

```
<body>
 <!-- html code -->
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </body>
```

Comment: Why do you place your JS file in the head?

Comment: No, I always place js file on end of the body, here I just show the file linking with out use url